# Limit of $\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{n=0}^{2^n-1}f(e^\frac{2k\pi}{2^n}i)$ for a complex-analytic function

Tags: convergence-divergence, laurent-series

Let consider a Laurent series $\displaystyle{ \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}a_kz^k }$ with complex coefficients and converging inside the annulus $A=\{\ z\in\mathbb C\ |\  r<|z|<R\ \}$, with $r<1<R$. We denote by $f(z)$ the sum of the series on $A$. To start, I don't have any assumption on the convergence on the boundary of the annulus.

I am interested in the sum $\displaystyle{S_n=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{n=0}^{2^n-1}f\left(e^\frac{2k\pi}{2^n}i\right)}$. It is easy to check that $2\pi S_n$ is the Riemann sum of the continuous function $F(t)=f(e^{it})$ for the equipartite subivision in $2^n$ parts of $[0,2\pi]$, hence $\displaystyle{ \lim_{n\to\infty} S_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}F(t)\ dt}$.

A  parametrization shows that $\displaystyle{ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}F(t)\ dt}$ is equal to $\displaystyle{ \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{C} \frac{f(z)}{z}\ dz }$ (where $C$ is the unit circle in $\mathbb C$), which in turn is equal to $a_0$ by the Residue Formula.

Therefore we proved

> Proposition: $$\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{n=0}^{2^n-1}f\left(e^\frac{2k\pi}{2^n}i\right)=a_0}$$

What happens to the limit of $S_n$ when $r=R=1$? Of course, if the series diverges at any point point of $C$ (e.g $\displaystyle{ \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}z^k }$), $f$ is not even defined.

To precise my question, I am looking for answers in 2 cases:

1. The case where the series converges on all $C$ (e.g $\displaystyle{ \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z, k\neq 0} \frac{z^k}{k^2} }$)? Will the above proposition still be true? If yes, how to prove it? Can I still expect $f$ to be continuous (so that my proof still holds)?
2. The case where the series converges for all roots of unity (or at least all the roots of $z^{2^n}=1$).

Comment: I doubt that $\sum_{k\neq 0} z^k k^2$ converges on $C$. (Actually, this converges to $-2\pi \delta''_1(z)$ in distribution sense, where $\delta_1(z)$ is the Dirac mass at $z = 1$.)

Comment: @SangchulLee: typo corrected. Thanks

Comment: Also, it seems that you already know that $F(t) = \sum_n a_n e^{int}$ is a Fourier series on $\Bbb{R}/2\pi \Bbb{Z}$. Have you tried some Fourier analysis on it?

Comment: @SangchulLee: My knowledge about Fourier series is actually near $0$, and I had a complex-analysis viewpoint on the question. Nevertheless, if it gives some insight on my question, I would be very happy about hearing about Fourier analysis.